# Syntax for adding inverted commas in T-SQL using Visual Studio (SQL)

Tags: sql, visual-studio, t-sql, replace

I have the following query in a report that I am writing in Visual Studio 2008. The parameter `@PostCode` is a comma-separated string of postcodes (first half only - i.e. everything in a postcode before the 'space'). The column `[PCode]` is the corresponding data (i.e. the first half of the postcode found in the column `[Postcode]`):

```
SELECT Title, Forename, Surname, Address1, Address2, Address3, Address4, Address5, Address6, Postcode, Local, [National], Code, PCode
FROM [database]
WHERE (PCode IN (REPLACE(@PostCode, ',', ''',''')))
```

What I want it to get it to replace the comma in the comma-separated string with a comma-surrounded-by-apostrophes. The reason being that I need the string to work for the "IN" look-up - for example, the string "

> NW13,NW14,NW15

would be rendered as

> NW13','NW14','NW15

At present, if there is only one value in the parameter (i.e. only one postcode to look up), then it returns the correct values. However, when there are multiple values in the parameter (comma separated), then no results are returned.

Can anyone tell me where in the syntax I am going wrong? Or can anyone suggest a better way of trying to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: "Inverted comma" = "apostrophe" or "single quote" in programming parlance.

Comment: Thanks @TimLehner. Can you help with the query, too?

Comment: Probably...please give a few examples of both PCode and @PostCode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we're working with delimited strings, `in` won't help you very much; it is meant for working with *sets* of data.

We can use `like` or even `patindex`, potentially.  It doesn't look like you need the apostrophes in either one if they aren't there already, but you do need to prepend and append both strings with the delimiters when searching.  Here is an example using `like`:

```
where ',' + @PostCode + ',' like '%,' + PCode + ',%'
```

Adding the delimiters in this fashion allows matching of the first, middle, and last items in a delimited list, and also avoids returning partial item matches (don't want to match `a` in `aa,bb`).

I'm assuming that `PCode` is a singular value, and `@PostCode` can contain a delimited string.

Comment: That's the bomb, @TimLehner ! Thanks very much indeed - have a great weekend.

Answer (score 0):

You could use dynamic sql for this:

```
DECLARE @PostCode VARCHAR(255) = '24557,36255,77737'
       ,@sql VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @sql = 'SELECT Title, Forename, Surname, Address1, Address2, Address3, Address4, Address5, Address6, Postcode, Local, [National], Code, PCode
            FROM [database]
            WHERE PCode IN ('+@PostCode+')
            '
EXEC (@sql)
```

Comment: I doubt this is the full answer, as `IN` doesn't work with delimited strings, only sets.

Comment: Good point, that was just what was needed to print what OP wanted, but simpler to do it as updated above.